# How do I make a regex to find the first instance of string somewhere after a first string is found

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse an output string of ffmpeg to get the width and height of the video stream

The contents look like this

```
Input #0
...
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: blah blah blah, 1024x768

Output #0
...  
 Stream #0:0(eng): Video: blah blah blah, 800x600
```

I want to capture the **1024x768** reliably (and not the 800x600)

I found something that got me close:

```
((\d{2,4})x(\d{2,4}))
```

this will match **1024x768 and 800x600** found in the output.
I just want the first one, and I'd like to ensure the one returned is always the one in the *Input #0* section

What I want is, "Regex, find me the first pattern of  numberxnumber that comes after the word Video, which comes after the word Stream #0"

I've looked all over and found some links about back-references but I can't get it working.

Comment: This seems like a lot to stuff into a regex. You *could* do something like `^Input #0.+(\d{2,4})x(\d{2,4})$`, assuming dot-matches-all and `^` and `$` match start/end of lines (and that there is definitely a resolution between it and the next "section header": `Output #0`). But it seems that this would be better suited to line-by-line analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Is this useful?

```
(Input #0).*?(\d+x\d+)
```

use the value from the second capture group..